# how to make symfony dump everything to screen

Tags: php, symfony1

hey folks, this is a really simple question. I'd like symfony to dump *everything* on its mind to the browser. I deployed to production, and nothing's working. not the logs, not the views, nothing. I just get a blank page.

is it possible to just see all of the [php/symfony] errors, somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a problem could have multiple source : apache (or any webserver), php, symfony, etc.

I would first try to use the "application_name_dev.php" front controller  on production server to see what's going on.

Then enabling log in production is a good idea, on both apache and symfony levels.

for the symfony part in factories.yml (in SF 1.4, don't know about other versions)

```
prod:   
  logger:
    class: sfAggregateLogger
    param:
      level: err
      loggers:
        sf_file_debug:
          class: sfFileLogger
          param:
            level: err
            file: %SF_LOG_DIR%/%SF_APP%_%SF_ENVIRONMENT%.log
```

We also use a hook that catch any uncaught exception and send us detail via email, but that's once the website is up

Answer (score 1):

Its generally not advisable to do this in production. Instead make sure you have `logging_enabled: true` in your `settings.yml` and then just look at the log file. If youre not getting anything inn your symfony logs, then take a look at the httpd `error_log`. If you really want to display errors take a look at the settings for the `dev` environment and copy the necessary settings to display errors.

However, you may still get the white screen of death if memory is being exhausted or the server is segfaulting.

Comment: thanks. that got me rolling, indirectly. it wasnt logging on my dev machine to the httpd logs, but here it was trying to.

Comment: `it wasnt logging on my dev machine to the httpd logs` - well that would be an apache config issue not so much Symfony.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still using Symfony2 you can try changing this line

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
```

to

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);
```

Source: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/environments.html